# hibernate transaction manager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, transactionmanager

I've a web-app deployed in a jboss env using spring and hibernate. 
The problem is that I keep having this message in my log :

```
12:28:44,895 FINE  [org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager] transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
```

Should I worry about it? All the data are corretly stored in the db (oracle) and everything seems to be working fine.

This is my configuration (db related):

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:jboss/datasources/DbDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ..
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

-->
 -->
 -->

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you getting session from sessionFactory? `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` or `sessionFactory.openSession()`

Comment: sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Comment: I'm not sure about transaction.auto_close_session parameter, I'm not sure that Spring closes sessions explicitly and not is relying on closing it with transaction(its wrappers just use hibernate transaction classes behind the scene) but I'm not at desktop to be 100% sure))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
```

Also, check following link for more details -

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-connection-release

Comment: Yes, I've already read it, but thanks for the hint.
In any case the auto should perform the after_statement release mode.